# Parameter in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

Basically i want to add a parameter on  column which is ID  in the  crystal reports with two options 
when 
option = 1 then result should be based of all ID's
or 
when I enter the ID in the parameter it should give me the result for only that particular ID

Comment: What have you tried already? Please post any relevant setup in your report and any code. You might also try Googling for a solution or a Crystal tutorial.

Comment: Show us your current data and desired one with a bit more information. If you do that we can try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/205398/Crystal-Report-Filtering-Using-Selection-Parameter) on what you are trying to achieve.
You basically create new Parameter on the report and bind to one of your fields on the report (ID in your case). Select Prompt for parameter option and there you go. 
Strongly suggest you google some more before posting a question.